# How to get add new item URL of a list?

Tags: 2007

I've an application where i show the bunch of lists in a site. I can click add new item right there and i want to redirect the user to the 'add new item URL' for the particular list he has selected. But the URLs are not uniform.

For ex -

For Tasks the add new item URL is `http://webapp1/Lists/Tasks/NewForm.aspx`.
For WorkFlow Tasks it is `http://webapp1/WorkFlowTasks/NewForm.aspx`

How can i get/built these URLs through code?

Comment: Okie i guess it is going to take a long time for me to get an answer here.

Comment: Long time, like 2 hours and 9 minutes?

Comment: Sorry for my bad comment. Apologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From MSDN article about [SPForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spform%28office.12%29.aspx) class:

> Use the [Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.forms%28office.12%29.aspx) property of the [SPList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist%28office.12%29.aspx)
>   class to return an [SPFormCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spformcollection%28office.12%29.aspx)
>   object that represents the collection
>   of forms for a list, and use an
>   indexer to return a single form from
>   the collection.

Sample:

```
SPWeb oWebsite = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPList oList = oWebsite.Lists["Contacts"];
SPFormCollection collForms = oList.Forms;
foreach (SPForm oForm in collForms)
{
    Response.Write(oForm.Url + " :: " + oForm.Type + "<BR>");
}
```

WorkFlow Tasks is usually system library (for workflow tasks) and you really should not allow people to add tasks in this one.

Use [SPList BaseTemplate property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.basetemplate%28office.12%29.aspx) to differentiate list types.

Comment: How can i substantially differentiate and identify System Libraries from other libraries?

Comment: Check BaseTemplate property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.basetemplate(office.12).aspx